# How to deleted nested comments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently did this tutorial http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/32-ruby-on-rails-3-2-blog-in-15-minutes-step-by-step, but im having trouble figuring out how to delete the comments once theyve been posted, ive tried the

method but that doesnt work as well as

it just return undefined method eror to me, what am i doing wrong

my code:

```
<%= div_for rep do %>
    <p>
        <div style="font-weight:bold; color:grey;"><%= rep.title %></div>
        <div><%= rep.body %></div>
            <strong style="font-size:8px;">
                    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(rep.created_at) %> ago
            </strong>
            <br/>
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', steppy_reps_path(@steppy, rep), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

the error:
No route matches [DELETE] "/steppies/11/reps.9"

routes.rb:

```
Testapp2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :steppies do
    resources :reps, :only => [:create]
  end

  get "steppies/ask"
  get "steppies/create"
  get "steppy/ask"
  get "steppy/create"
end
```

rake route output:

```
   steppy_reps POST   /steppies/:steppy_id/reps(.:format)     reps#create
    steppy_rep DELETE /steppies/:steppy_id/reps/:id(.:format) reps#destroy
      steppies GET    /steppies(.:format)                     steppies#index
               POST   /steppies(.:format)                     steppies#create
    new_steppy GET    /steppies/new(.:format)                 steppies#new
   edit_steppy GET    /steppies/:id/edit(.:format)            steppies#edit
        steppy GET    /steppies/:id(.:format)                 steppies#show
               PUT    /steppies/:id(.:format)                 steppies#update
               DELETE /steppies/:id(.:format)                 steppies#destroy
  steppies_ask GET    /steppies/ask(.:format)                 steppies#ask
teppies_create GET    /steppies/create(.:format)              steppies#create
    steppy_ask GET    /steppy/ask(.:format)                   steppy#ask
 steppy_create GET    /steppy/create(.:format)                steppy#create
```

Comment: Please add your code and the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Please put that in the question and include your `routes.rb` contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the action to your `routes.rb` file.

```
resources :steppies do
  resources :reps, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Also, the form needs to use a different route.

```
steppy_rep_path(@steppy, rep)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it still gives me the same error after adding the :destroy action

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Try remove the whole `only` clause.

Comment: to this? resources :reps => [:create, :destroy]

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: i put it in the question

Comment: It appears that the URL is not being generated correctly. Are you sure it is `/steppies/11/reps.9` and not `/steppies/11/reps/9`?

Comment: when i click on destroy it goes to http://localhost:3000/steppies/1/reps.9, but im guessing its supposed to goto http://localhost:3000/steppies/1/reps/9?

Comment: Found it! You need a different route name.

Comment: oh my goodness, thanks but now yet again i get another error, Unknown action

The action 'destroy' could not be found for RepsController, i added def destroy end to the controller, but im not sure of the code to go in between since its a nested resources, and once i did that it gave a tamplate missing error

Comment: You need a `destroy` method in the controller.

Comment: do you know how i can define this method?

Comment: i put this is: @rep = Rep.find(params[:id]).destroy, but still the same

Comment: sorry to mass text, i think i figured it out, the only thing missing now i belive is the redirect method, which i put to redirect_to @steppy

Comment: and which returns: Cannot redirect to nil!, so im kinda lost here

Comment: You need to redirect to the `steppy` object which you can find using `params[:steppy_id]`